# What to do with such an error in Telethon?

Tags: telethon

Hello everyone Please help me!

I get this error in Powershell:

```
Please enter your phone (or bot token): (phone number)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Telegram Desktop\backup_will_be_inside_me\backup_script.py", line 13, in <module>
      client.start()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 128, in start
      else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
      return future.result()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 184, in _start
      await self.send_code_request(phone, force_sms=force_sms)
      File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 434, in send_code_request
      result = await self(functions.auth.SendCodeRequest(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in call
      return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 67, in _call
      future = sender.send(request, ordered=ordered)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 181, in send
      state = RequestState(request)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\network\requeststate.py", line 17, in init
      self.data = bytes(request)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\tlobject.py", line 194, in bytes
      return self._bytes()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\functions\auth.py", line 644, in _bytes
      self.serialize_bytes(self.api_hash),
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\tlobject.py", line 112, in serialize_bytes
      raise TypeError(
      TypeError: bytes or str expected, not <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you passed as the third parameter to the `TelegramClient` constructor of in the v1 version of the library (the `api_hash`) was an `int`. You have to pass a `string`. You can obtain it from https://my.telegram.org.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it didn't work